# View positioned incorrectly when set to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, landscape, uinavigationitem

My iPhone application is navigation-based and contains a lot of portrait-only views and one landscape-only view for viewing images. So I'd like to force this landscape-only view to automatically rotate to lanscape even if device is positioned in portrait mode.

So here is what I'w done in that view's controller:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight); 
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

 _originalTransform = [[appDelegate navigationController].view transform];
 _originalBounds = [[appDelegate navigationController].view bounds];
 _originalCenter = [[appDelegate navigationController].view center];

 CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
 landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, +80.0, +100.0);

 [[appDelegate navigationController].view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

 [appDelegate navigationController].view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
 [appDelegate navigationController].view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
 [appDelegate navigationController].view.center  = CGPointMake (240.0, 160.0);

 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
 }
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [[appDelegate navigationController].view setTransform:_originalTransform];
 [[appDelegate navigationController].view setBounds:_originalBounds];
 [[appDelegate navigationController].view setCenter:_originalCenter];

 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait; 
}
```

Now I've got that view always shown in lanscape mode. But there is one problem. This view is positioned incorrectly as shown in [this screenshot](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/5582/screenshot2010011814533.png).

I tried to manually set the frame after rotation but it didn't help. Also I didn't find a complete guide how to set one view to be landscape-only. **Please help me with this problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this guy's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation/186589#186589).  Basically you need to transform around the center of the window.  Looks like you may also need to rotate the status bar.

A different method would be to use UIDevice setDeviceOrientation, but that's a private API and thus not a great solution.

Comment: Thanks, I tried many workarounds and they helped me. But there is still one problem with portrait modal dialog that is shown above that landscape dialog. So after many hours I decided to let the initial dialog to be portrait and landscape. This fixed all my troubles. Blame to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method after you have applied the transformation:

```
[self.view sizeToFit];
```