# iphone's rotated view doesn't take up whole screen

Tags: iphone, view, rotation

I rotated a view using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation. ( [iPhone - allow landscape orientation on just one viewcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144520/iphone-allow-landscape-orientation-on-just-one-viewcontroller) )

As you can see below, the images have white region in left and right.
I want the image take up the whole space with black background.(at least in one dimension, width or height )

[image]

Below is the full code

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.imageView.opaque = NO;
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.jsonAlbumImage.url_image
                                           relativeToURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@URL_BASE]]
                   placeholderImage: [GlobalHelper placeHolderImage]];

    [self.view addSubview: self.imageView];

}

- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0)];
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0)];
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)];
    }
}
```

-- EDIT --

What worked for me in the end .. don't know why modification does work.. any explanation would be great!

```
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];

    CGAffineTransform t;
    CGRect rect;
    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
        rect = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0);
        rect = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
        rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
        rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    }
    else
        return; // looks like there are other orientations than the specified 4

    [self.view setTransform:t];
    self.view.bounds = rect;
```

Comment: it looks like it is taking up the whole view in height. If the view is taller than it is wide, this would be the desired behavior.

Comment: no there's black background which is not taken up by image on both top and bottom

Comment: have you given the proper content mode for the imageview

Comment: log the bounds of controller's view and image view and check

Comment: they are both (320,480) even when rotated. Yes I tried setting 480,320 to view.frame imageView.frame, but did not fix the issue.. maybe I shouldn't set origin of the frame? .. brb

Comment: Doesn't work..    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGRect temp = self.view.frame;
        temp.size.width = screenRect.size.height;
        temp.size.height = screenRect.size.width;
        self.view.frame = temp;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification`, you need to relayout your views so that they occupy all the space available. You could do something like this:

```
- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];

  CGAffineTransform t;
  if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
  } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0);
  } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
  } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
  }

  CGPoint screenCenter = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.width/2,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.height/2);
  self.view.center = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(screenCenter, t);
  self.view.bounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds, t);
  [self.view setTransform:t];

}
```

Where :

> CGRectApplyAffineTransform
>
> Applies an affine transform to a rectangle.
>
> ```
>        CGRect CGRectApplyAffineTransform (
>            CGRect rect,
>            CGAffineTransform t
>          );
> ```

Try also removing this line:

```
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

You don´t need it if you are not going to use autorotation and I fear it might conflict with your own setting the view's frame. This is just an hypothesis to account for the fact that you are not seeing the view´s frame change.

EDIT:

> I'd very much like to know what this transform thing does

well, the transform is doing the rotation.

rotating is relative to an anchor point which is used as a pivot; what happens is that if the anchor point is not in the middle of the view being rotated, then the view is also translated (imagine a rotation around a vertex).

So, it is correct to set the bounds to make things even; indeed I was suggesting just that with the lines:

```
  self.view.center = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(screenCenter, t);
  self.view.bounds = CGRectApplyAffineTransform([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds, t);
```

but possibly the idea of applying the same transform to both the center and the bounds was not blessed. (that is also why I asked for some traces, to see what was happening :-)

Comment: CGRectApplyCGAffineTransform's return value is int..  Would you mind explaining why removing the autoresizingMask can help the situation?

Comment: Sorry, the correct spelling was `CGRectApplyAffineTransform`. See my edited answer for more details.

Comment: tried it, and doesn't work.. image dissappears in other rotations than portrait. I logged view/imageView's bounds, and it is (480,320)

Comment: that´s good for a start. what about setting the view center like I suggest in my edited answer?

Comment: got little better, if I rotate to vertical(becomes all white), then come back to portrait, image is there..

Comment: some NSLog here and there would help understanding what is happening, really... :-)

Comment: Thank you for help! I'd very much like to know what this transform thing does.. but.. in the mean time, I did set rect = cgrectmake(0,0,480,320) on landscape (320,480) on portrait..  `[self.view setTransform:t];
 self.view.bounds = rect;` and it works fine.(after the main if-else block of code), i'll post the code in the question.

Comment: I think what you do is perfectly fine. See my edit for more clarifications.