# How to rotate orientation of UIImage when application have only one orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, screen-orientation

I have a Tabbar based application in iOS and it is only portrait orientation enabled. one of my controller presents a controller with only one photo and i have to enable all orientations for image. can any one suggest me how should i do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144520/iphone-allow-landscape-orientation-on-just-one-viewcontroller

Comment: thats my answer thanks

Comment: but still t is just rotating my image view also rotate but do not set it self as it should be

Answer (score 0):

> I think,
>
> You have to enable all the Rotation in Project Summary.
>
> Then Restrict the All Views except Photo View.

Comment: when we are using Tabbarcontroller in that case if we enable rotation then it will enable in whole project and if i try to restrict it in any controller then it is not possible to do