# Set orientation to Portrait in one view when the navigation controller is portrait

Tags: iphone, xcode, orientation

If my application is in the Landscape position and then they press a button to load the info view, how can I set the info view to only support the portrait position, and therefore change the orientation to portrait when the view is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
[application setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
```

Comment: I tried that before, The screen turns out like this though: http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/8808/screenshot20101213at200.png

Comment: Looks like this is more complicated than it should have been... Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation and you'll find a lot of ideas to play with.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait == interfaceOrientation )
}
```

Comment: This won't force it to turn to portrait if it's currently in landscape mode when loaded.

Comment: That doesn't work the Info View is still in landscape mode from the device being in landscape.

Comment: Interface orientation is an immutable property. I'm not sure you could do this the way you want to. I would design the view in interface builder the way you want it to look from landscape and load it as normal.