# What is the proper way to set an iPhone's orientation programmatically?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, orientation, screen-orientation

Will Apple accept the following code?

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];`

When I write this, I see the following warning:

> warning: 'UIDevice' may not respond to '-setOrientation:'

So what can I do to set the iPhone's orientation programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

After writing `[[UIDevice currentDevice] set ];`, do you find option for `setOrientation`? Definitely it is a private API. Don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation) It has a long discussion with lots of code snippets about how to deal with the orientation and what to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple rejects applications which use this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the method in a category in the .h or .m file of wherever you use it.

```
@interface UIDevice (MyPrivateNameThatAppleWouldNeverUseGoesHere)

-(void) setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;

@end
```

but also Apple rejects applications which use this code.
So, use this for solution for call orienatation method.. and it works fine

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectZero;

[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

[viewController release];

sorry, if there is any mistake. i'm a fresher for iphone... :)