# How can i Navigate screen to landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone

I am making a view based application. For one of the xib files, I want it to only appear in landscape mode. And When i click a button in the first page it should automatically rotate to landscape and navigate to the new screen which should be in Landscape orientation.

How do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `UINavigationController` then you will not be able to navigate from portrait to landscape, you will need to present your new view controller modally, not to push it
Check this answer [Force UIViewController to only show in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339662/force-uiviewcontroller-to-only-show-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 0):

In the view that should be in landscape orientation , add this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||  interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```