# Force ViewController to animate to landscape

Tags: ios, landscape, viewcontroller

I have got an app (ios 6 only) with a navigation controller as the root and multiple view controller pushing to push. 
one viewController I want to push, should always view in landscape mode. 
I would like to push to the viewController and animate to landscape automatically.

how can i do that?

thanks, raphael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339662/force-uiviewcontroller-to-only-show-in-landscape-mode

Comment: Here is my approach for a similar issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491786/force-landscape-viewcontroller-in-ios-7/22491787#22491787