# How to force UIViewCotroller to be in only in Landscape mode

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8, screen-orientation

I'm developing an iOS app using Swift and my app should be in portrait mode. 
I have one on view to capture images. I want to display that view only in landscape mode. This app is for iOS 7 or above.

In the project "**General**" **Device Orientation** is set as "**Portrait**"

In the storyboard **Simulated Metrics** section the orientation is set as "Landscape"

Above image shows the UIViewController settings in the storyboard and following code is in the UIViewConroller.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int
{
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeRight.rawValue)
}
```

This doesn't give the expected output.

I'm new to iOS development I have no idea how to achieve this.

Any ideas please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force UIViewController to only show in landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339662/force-uiviewcontroller-to-only-show-in-landscape-mode)

Comment: @Kamaros Unless you know of a way that this can be done purely through interface builder without writing any code, this can't really be a duplicate of an Objective-C question.

Comment: @nhgrif Swift and ObjC can use the same frameworks, unless it's a language-specific question, it can totally be a duplicate of an ObjC question.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez The discussions on the meta don't tend to agree with your statement.  VB and C# questions aren't being closed as duplicates of each other.

Answer (score -3):

In the project settings you can restrict all views to conform to a single display mode. If you want to restrict just one view, you must do it in code.

Look up "willTransitionToTraitCollection".

Comment: This answer doesn't address solving the problem for a single view or view controller.

Answer (score -3):

Click On the project->Click on Target->General->Device Orientaion.Uncheck whichever you don't want.[image]

Comment: This answer doesn't address solving the problem for a single view or view controller.