# Can apple reject force change orientation?

Tags: ios, iphone, uideviceorientation

To force change device orientation, I take code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650137/how-to-change-the-device-orientation-programmatically-in-ios-6/21142932#21142932)

but can apple reject app that use `setOrientation:` ? 
have some one experience?

or may be someone have 100% work and not can be rejected by Apple, solution?

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)]) {
            int orientationPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            NSMethodSignature *sig = [[UIDevice currentDevice] methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)];
            NSInvocation* invo = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
            [invo setTarget:[UIDevice currentDevice]];
            [invo setSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)];
            [invo setArgument:&orientationPortrait atIndex:2];
            [invo invoke];
        }
    }
```

Ok, thanks, I will try with this snippet.

Comment: you better ask Apple, they are the only reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7280833/986169 A bit old but I think it is still relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, Apple will reject on the basis of force orientation. Some times it is requirement and only way to view in landscape/portrait. Apple will **not REJECT** .

Comment: did you ever try it ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7280833/986169. A bit old but I think it still relevant

Comment: Yes My aap is on store which have many view in single mode. You can try meu messaging from app Store. If accept answer upvote as well

Comment: You are aware that not every single bit is tested and Apple might skipped that one. What I'm saying that without a proven quote from Apple rules this is a big risk to take

Comment: Rejection is on the basis of duplicate design or some thing like that or if you private code/lib of Apple.

Comment: Rejection can happen on various reasons, and I insist the only reference is Apple.

Comment: http://flippa.com/blog/rejected-ios-app/

http://blog.sensortower.com/blog/2013/09/09/10-ways-to-avoid-apple-app-store-rejection/

Comment: In my situation, in uiwebview playin video, and when I make it full screen from portrait mode, my customer want to support all orientation in fullscreen mode, but when off fullscreen make all in portrait.

Comment: Apple will sometimes reject if you support landscape left, but not landscape right. Sometimes they don't, but I've seen it happen. That's an edge case though and hopefully you wouldn't code that way anyway!