# one view in landscape giving warning

Tags: iphone, warnings, landscape, viewcontroller

I need just one view in my app to show in landscape, all is working but Im getting a warning I would like to get rid off, this is the code in the view controller for that view..

in viewDidLoad

```
       [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

and,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

but I get the warning

> UIDevice may not respont to -setOrientation:

in my viewDidLoad,

it works, but I dont like that warning, so how to fix this please??

thanks a lot!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the orientation property on UIDevice is read-only and you should not be setting it.

Read the [Link that Max posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation) to find the proper way to set up an application to run in landscape mode.