# Rotate the Simulator at launch Time

Tags: iphone

i m working on a project in which i want to rotate the ipad at the launch time.i have done coded for it.But it still not working. code i have written-

in .m file

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[[UIDevice currentDevice]setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
     return (interfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add "Initial interface orientation" to your info plist and set the value to "Landscape (right home button)". The type is String I think.

Answer (score 0):

See previous answers on this topic [Is there a documented way to set the iPhone orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

Add Initial interface orientation to tour info.plist and set its value as Landscape (right home button)