# Orientations support

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an app with some views, I need one view to rotate. that view is called by pushviewcontroller. all these views are inside a tabbarcontroller.

I already edit the info.plist to support orientations I added this items to Supported interface orientations:
Landscape (left home button)
Landscape (right home button)

and also added this to the view i want to rotate

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return YES;    
}
```

but it doesnt work.

what do i need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UITabBarController have a some problem. the problems is a subviews(selected index) not autorotate.

So, you can make a category, and add a below code.

and, add a #import "UITabBarController+Autorotate.h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface UITabBarController (Autorotate)

@end
```

---

```
#import "UITabBarController+Autorotate.h"


@implementation UITabBarController (Autorotate)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    UIViewController *controller = self.selectedViewController;
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        controller = [(UINavigationController *)controller visibleViewController];
    return [controller shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```

Comment: but from the tabbar I load a view and from that view I push the view that I want to rotate. where should I put that code ? thanks by the way my tabbarconroller is in my delegate

Comment: File-New-New File- [Objective-C category] create
You can make a category. and add a code. and in your view add a #import and normally use a shouldAutorotate Method.

Comment: Thanks!!! it works. just one more question, I have load an image from internet but when the iPhone is in landscape how can I resize it or call another view thanks

Comment: <view.autoresizingMask> using this method. 
refer a apple reference. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: can you help me with something else, when i am in the pushedview and I return to the view that pushed it it mantains the landscape mode ! how do i force it to return to portrait ? thanks

Comment: refer a this link. maybe your issue same.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation