# Navigation Bar issue in orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, orientation

I searched every where but not find the solution of this I am New in iphone.In every where I got the set the height of navigation or my view is not rotating in orientation like issue.my view is rotating but my navigation bar is on same position please some one help me if You have solution.Thanks I have show my some code in down which I used for Orientation.when I tap on my tab bar my simulator is automatic rotate and I want tab bar also rotate but using this code only simulator is rotate not tab bar and navigation bar and sorry for my bad english.

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) 
{

    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^ {

    [self.navigationController.view setTransform:transform];

}];

[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: navigation bar is automatic rotated. when Orientation is change.  And commit ur This line //[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];   ... try it

Comment: @Ayaz Thanks but this solution is not works in my code its stop my automatic simulator orientation.I just want to rotate navigation bar rotate my view already rotating if you have solution help me buddy thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is, no offense intended, very curious. I'm not sure what you are trying to do. What problem are you trying to solve? Playing around with CGAffineTransform's can definitely generate strange results like what you describe if you're not very careful.

If you just want to make sure that your app successfully supports landscape and portrait orientations, you can implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in your view controller. When you do this, all of the various controls will reorient themselves accordingly.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Support all orientations on iPad
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
        return YES;

    // otherwise, for iPhone, support portrait and landscape left and right

    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) ||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

But if I have misunderstood what you're trying to do, i.e., you're trying to do something more sophisticated than just supporting both landscape and portrait orientation, let me know.

---

I apologize because I don't remember where I originally got this code (but it's referenced in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation)), but the following can be used to force landscape orientation:

First, make sure that your shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation should read as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
        (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Second, in viewDidLoad, add the following code:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *view = [window.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    [view removeFromSuperview];
    [window addSubview:view];
}
```

For some reason, removing the view from the main window and then re-adding it forces it to query shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and set the orientation correctly. Given that this isn't an Apple approved approach, maybe one should refrain from using it, but it works for me. Your mileage may vary. But [that SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation) also refers to other techniques, too.

Comment: Thanks Ryan its works fine but one error its show only once when first we move to that screen after back if we again move to that screen it will not work I post ur code in view will appair also but its have same problem but I tried to resolve that thanks till now.