# Device orientation is not changing in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, device-orientation, ipad-2

I'm using an iPAD 2 with OS version 9.3. My application tries to change the device orientation but its not changing. How to change device orientation in iOS 9.0. My question is when app is started it should be Portrait and should not autorotate. After button click it should change orientation to LandscapeRight.

And for your info all orientations are checked in project .plist file

My code in my view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];    
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];   
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

and on a button click

```
-(IBAction)playMyVideo:(MPMediaItem*)item{        
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]
                                forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

What is the problem with the code? If there isn't any problem what is the solution for this?

**Note: In iPhone there is an app called Videos he is handling the rotation on button clicks. Its a system app. How is he doing that.**

Comment: are you want to display view controller on portrait mode only

Comment: did you check all orientation in general tab ?

Comment: Read the question carefully guys. @KKRocks and Bupat Bheda. All orientations are checked.

Comment: i read it carefully then i asking you .

Comment: Who is that hopeless guy down voted my question without commenting ? @Moderator Please pay some attention here

Comment: Guys, guys, stop down voting, answer the question man...!

Comment: try your Code in viewdidload not in viewDidAppear

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj That also tried not working

Comment: is the ipad orientation lock is ON ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri No Lock is OFF

Comment: try return YES in autorotate method.

Comment: -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
} // add these

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That will auto rotate eveyway. I dont want that. I want rotation on button clicks. But autorotation should be shut.

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj Please understand I don't want auto rotation. I want rotation on button clicks. And please give an answer .

Comment: There is no officially documented way to do what you are asking for.  There are several workarounds posted under this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation -  but most of them are kludges and will probably break in future versions of iOS (if they haven't already), or will get your app rejected on app store submission.  Apple doesn't want you setting the orientation manually because they feel it will confuse users and it breaks their UI design guidelines.

Comment: there is One way, use 2 viewcontroller objects... one with portrait and other landscape Orientation. this will work Smooth

Comment: Wow Seems hopeful @ajjjjjjjj, I'll try.

Comment: hi dear , Any update

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported way to do what you are asking for. There are several workarounds posted under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/is-there-a-documented-way-to-set-the-iphone-orientation) but most of them are kludges and will probably break in future versions of iOS (if they haven't already), or will get your app rejected on app store submission. Apple doesn't want you setting the orientation manually because they feel it will confuse users and it breaks their UI design guidelines.

See Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/layout/) document for reference.

Comment: Then how the apple guy is doing the same thing in his app Videos.

Answer (score 0):

there is One way, use 2 `UIViewController` objects... one with portrait and other landscape Orientation. this will work Smooth. except that no way